# creating instance using self as argument

Tags: java, constructor, doubly-linked-list

creating a doubly linked list with one node that points to itself

```
public DList(){
 Dnode sentinel= new DNode(sentinel, null, sentinel);
}
```

for reference, Dnode constructor takes DNode(Dnode p, Object 0, Dnode n)

Is this valid code?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not valid.

You can't cant use `sentinel` variable in the expression that defines it.

You can however have a constructor, which makes the previous and next elements be itself (`this`):

```
class DList {
    DList previous, next;

    public DList() {
        previous  = this;
        next = this;
    }
}
```